C# HttpRequestMessage.GetClientCertificate() returning null
I'm trying to implement simple SSL/TLS certificate validation in a Web API.
I'm following this Microsoft documentation but when I send the request through Postman, it doesn't find any certificates.
That's all I've done and tried so far:
AuthorizationFilterAttribute
public class RequireCertificateAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
        {
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
            {
                ReasonPhrase = "HTTPS Required"
            };
        }
        else
        {
            X509Certificate2 cert = actionContext.Request.GetClientCertificate();

            if (cert == null)
            {
                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                {
                    ReasonPhrase = "Client Certificate Required"
                };

            }

            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
        }
    }
}

My endpoint
[RequireCertificate]
[HttpGet]
[Route("ssl/test")]
public IHttpActionResult SslTest()
{
    return Ok();
}

Project properties with SSL enabled

Self-signed SSL Certificate generate by the command below
makecert.exe -n "CN=Development CA" -r -sv TempCA.pvk TempCA.cer

And the client certificate
makecert.exe -pe -ss My -sr CurrentUser -a sha1 -sky exchange -n "CN=name" -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2 -sk SignedByCA -ic TempCA.cer -iv TempCA.pvk

The ssl flags I added to my IISExpress "applicationhost.config" located at "Documents\IISExpress\config"

I also added the flags in the project configuration file.
This is how I added the exported client certificate in Postman:


I also tried to export the PFX file, but got the same results
This is what I get with the request:

Null certificate:

I'm using .net framework 4.8
What I'm missing?
